# Android: Get Date from DatePickerDialog.Builder

Tags: android

How do I get the date from DatePickerDialog.Builder?

```
public void methodOne{
    final DatePickerDialog.Builder alert = new DatePickerDialog.Builder(this);
                alert.setTitle("Set Recurring Event");
                alert.setMessage("Pick the maximum date for the event: ");

                alert.setPositiveButton("Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //Get date and start setting appointments

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                alert.show();
...
}
```

I'm aware that there is the documentation, and that DatePickerDialog allows for  getDatePicker(), which accordingly allows access to the "DatePicker contained in this dialog." But this does not extend to DatePickerDialog.Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little tutorial.
Use this to generate a date  picker dialog

```
new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateListener, year, month, day);
```

And use this listener to listen for date

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() { 
@Override 
public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) { 
    // SET YOUR VALUES HERE
    // arg1 = year 
    // arg2 = month 
    // arg3 = day       
 });
```

You have to initiate year, month and day with type `int` in `onCreate` or globally before calling method.

Reference: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_datepicker_control.htm

If you want example which works within `activity` then follow this reference: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/